# Why google removes appengine icon from account products page?

Tags: google-app-engine

To access my GAE application I usually click on GAE icon on that page but when google remove it I'm worry about will Google going to stop this service like it did with some of their products like Knol, because I'm going to start up my business by using appengine in next few mounts.

Answer (score 1):

App engine is here to stay.

According to Google's own policy statement you get a years notice of any change that might break any GAE application. There are tens of thousands of business running on GAE and it's not  in any danger of vanishing.

http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html

> Google App Engine, Google Maps/Earth APIs and YouTube API will wind down their current 3-year deprecation policy and will transition to the one-year policy in April 2014. Google Cloud Storage keeps its current one-year policy. To be very clear, we are not deprecating the APIs themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It help me to create the app without worry.

Comment: I'm also fully committed to using app engine as a platform for business.

Comment: The first line of your answer suggests to me that app engine will fail, which I think is not what you intend.